# Paginating search results in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-1.3

I have CakePHP 1.3.5 site with built in search. The problem is that search results are too many to show in one screen and the search process takes a lot of time (over 30seconds).

In controler I have:

```
public function search() {
    $regions = $this->RealEstate->Region->find('list');
    $realEstateCategories = $this->RealEstate->realEstateCategories();
    $realEstateTypes = $this->RealEstate->RealEstateType->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('regions', 'realEstateCategories', 'realEstateTypes'));
}

public function results($local = false) {
    if (!$this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
        $this->cakeError('error404');
    }
    if ($local) {
        $params = $this->_myEstatesCriteria();
        $this->set(compact('local'));
        $realEstates = $this->RealEstate->search($this->data, $params['conditions']);
    } else {
        $realEstates = $this->RealEstate->search($this->data);
    }
    $this->layout = '';
    $this->set(compact('realEstates'));
}
```

I set limit in conditions and tried this, but got no results.

```
$this->paginate = $this->RealEstate->search($this->data);
$realEstates = $this->paginate();
```

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html Go through this.

Comment: He is using 1.3, not 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Check [the official documentation about pagination for CakePHP 1.3](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Common-Tasks-With-CakePHP/Pagination.html), it explains in detail how the paginator works. You last code snippet clearly shows that you don't know how to use it. The paginator itself will pull the data for you, you don't pass a result set to the paginator. Just check the documentation, everything is there.

Example taken from the documentation:

```
public function list_recipes() {
    $this->paginate = array(
        'conditions' => array('Recipe.title LIKE' => 'a%'),
        'limit' => 10
    );
    $data = $this->paginate('Recipe');
    $this->set(compact('data'));
);
```

Comment: Do you mean that all this conditions, which now are in the model, must be in the controller function?
http://pastebin.com/AGtTnN1R

Comment: No, fat models are good. The example shows that you just have to set the conditions to the paginate property. Read the documentation. You can do this for example: $this->paginate = $this->Model->getYourPaginationSettings();

Comment: Ok, I think I did it, now I got the first page of results, but when I place `echo $this->paginator->numbers();` I get internal error 500 and I don't kno if this is page 1 or just a limited result...